# MVC controller returns JSON. But to where?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, controller

i'm new to MVC. So a MVC controller mainly returns a viewresult. i understand it will be the view has the same action name. 
Let's say "DoSomething" action goes to "DoSomething" view. But if the controller returns a JSON, to where is it returned to?
Is it going to the page where the action method was activated from?
Let's say "Index" vew to "DoSomething" action. If "DoSomething" controller returns a JSON, does the JSON go to "Index" view?
I was working out with returning a JSON and JQuery call ajax, but am confused.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an `Action Method` returns Json, the `View` doesn't get involved. In all cases, an action method of a controller returns something to response stream. Notice the return statement below. Actually it's calling the view first. Think of it like a method call. And then whatever the `view` is, is returned.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
     return View();
}
```

In Json's case notice the `view` stays out of it:

```
public JsonResult DoSomething()
{
     var jsondata = {
     "name"    : "Mike",
     "address" : "home",
     "gender"  : "male"
    };
     return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

jsondata will be caught by javascript.